# Customise Netsuite Site Builder Cart

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

So I've been tasked with getting a custom item field value displayed on an item in the cart of a site-builder site.

I have experience with SCA but not so much when it comes to site builder. I can see how templates are put together and how to display data in these templates.

I can also tell that it is possible to add or remove field sets from the cart in the 'Set Up Website' tab.

Another thing to note is that the Live Hosting Files are empty.. which is where I would have expected to find the scripts that would create the cart.

So my question is, how do I either create a new row in the 'Set Up Website => Cart' tab to display this new custom field. Or where can I find and edit the template/script that creates the cart?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Is this the old SiteBuilder Cart or from the new SiteBuilder Extensions? If so, which version? The old, original SiteBuilder Cart is really difficult to add customizations such as a custom field. I would do it by running an AJAX call on a SuiteScript to get the needed data that write it into the cart cell. It was a hack but at least I was able to customize it.

The SB Extensions work a lot like SCA, and it what to do depends upon the version. If it is only for the cart, then just extend Item Keys Mapping and then it will be available on the template file. If you also need it on the cart summary in the checkout then, see SuiteAnswers for the specifics for the various versions.

Comment: Hey Sam, we've actually outsourced this as it was using the older Sitebuilder. I've actually looked at those extensions but the client did not want to go down that path. I actually checked out your website when looking for answers to this, (I'm assuming its yours as it's your last name!) and the docs on there were really helpful.